# SUM () in a where - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, having-clause

The query below shows results of a contract, whose contract delay is `between 1 and 487 days`.

Now I want to add the values ​​of the invoices belonging to the `invoice.value` contract and then filter by the balance of the contract, whose total is between one value and another.

In this case I would have 8 results that would fit the query below, with the balance of the contract `between 4 and 5 dolars and delay between 1 and 487 days`, but I only get 1 result, and yet, incorrect.

What am I doing wrong ?

**tb_contract**

```
id
contract
```

**tb_invoice**

```
id
contract_id
value
due_date
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contract`.*
FROM `tb_contract` `contract`
LEFT JOIN `tb_invoice` `invoice` ON `invoice`.`contract_id` = `contract`.`id`
WHERE `contract`.`creditor_id` = '5ddf5246-fed4-4e5f-538d-34df1e8cf9ee'
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) >= 1
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) <= 487
GROUP BY `contract`
HAVING SUM(invoice.value) between 4.00 AND 5.00
```

[image]

not using Haveing ​​and using where `invoice.value`, I receive a contract that has at least 1 invoice that fits the parameters of the values, however it brings other invoices from the same contract that contains several other values ​​above the parameters of the consultation. What I want is to add all the invoices of the contract and filter only are between the parameters of the values. In other words, adding up all contract invoices cannot be lower or higher than the amounts

**That would be the other query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contract`.*
FROM `tb_contract` `contract` LEFT JOIN `tb_invoice` `invoice` ON `invoice`.`contract_id` = `contract`.`id`
WHERE `contract`.`creditor_id` = '5ddf5246-fed4-4e5f-538d-34df1e8cf9ee'
AND `invoice`.`value` between 4.00 AND 5.00
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) >= 1
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) <= 487
```

Comment: Probably learning how to use a proper `GROUP BY` will be a good start.  The query shouldn't have executed because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Pls add some sample data, exoected results and actual results tl your query to help us understand the question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suspicious about the `group by` clause: is `contract` an actual column in any of the table that comes into play in the query? For your query to be valid SQL, it would need to be the primary key of the contracts table.

I also suspect that you want contracts whose *all invoices* belong to the given date interval - so the conditions on the date should be moved to the `having`  clause.

Overall, I think that this would be simpler and more efficiently expressed by joining the contract table with a aggregated subquery on the invoices:

```
select c.*, i.total_value
from tb_contract contract c
inner join (
    select contract_id, sum(value) total_value
    from tb_invoice
    group by contract_id
    having 
        max(i.due_date) >= current_date - interval 487 day
        and min(i.due_date) < current_date
        and sum(value) >= 4 
        and sum(value) <  5
) i on i.contract_id = c.id
where c.creditor_id = '5ddf5246-fed4-4e5f-538d-34df1e8cf9ee'
```

Comment: `Anyway, you should repeat all non-aggregated columns in the select clause in the group by clause, otherwise your query is not valid standard SQL` this is not true for several years, functionally dependent columns do not need to be listed in the group by. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html

Comment: @gmb, this works for me, but the initial delay is also a parameter! So, how can I use it?

Comment: @WagnerFillio: doesn't the `interval` expression accept a parameter? `max(i.due_date) >= current_date - interval ? day and min(i.due_date) <= current_date - ? day`

Comment: @GMB, `invoice.due_date) >= 1` where `1` is a variable parameter coming from POST

Comment: @WagnerFillio: you should be able to pass the variable in the `interval` expression. Or you can switch back to your original `datediff()`  expression (but note that this is less efficient than the interval solution).

Comment: @GMB, perfect, I can adapt, thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `contract`.*,SUM(invoice.value) AS inv_tot
FROM `tb_contract` `contract`
LEFT JOIN `tb_invoice` `invoice` ON `invoice`.`contract_id` = `contract`.`id`
WHERE `contract`.`creditor_id` = '5ddf5246-fed4-4e5f-538d-34df1e8cf9ee'
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) >= 1
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) <= 487
GROUP BY `contract`
HAVING inv_tot between 4.00 AND 5.00
```

Comment: In this case, I obtained the result of a contract that contains 2 invoices, 1 invoice with a value of 4.84 and another with a value of 74.34. The balance of this contract is 79.18.

Comment: So in above example you given, What should be desired output for contract 1550528 ?

Comment: is a query that brings several contracts, and the purpose is to filter by the parameters and bring only those that fit the parameters